# SQL Query that joins one table where the second table has duplicates

Tags: sql, join, duplicates

I have 2 tables Joined by StudentID and ParkingID. My Table B has duplicate parking information. Im looking to get StudentID, StudentName, ParkingSpace number and the count of duplicates. This is my first post so forgive me if I dont follow all the correct protocols here. I appreciate the help.

Example:

```
Table A:

StudentID     StudentName
----          ------
001           Mary
002           Jane
003           Peter
004           Smith
005           Kathy

Table B:

ParkingID     ParkingSpace
-----         -----
001           25
001           25
002           18
003           74
004           22
005           31
005           31
005           31
005           31
005           31
```

This is my goal.

```
StudentID     StudentName  ParkingSpace  dupCount
----          ------       ------        ------
001           Mary         25            2
005           Kathy        31            5
```

Comment: And how are the two tables linked?

Comment: StudentID and ParkingID

Comment: So StudentID and ParkingID represent the same thing? If so you might consider naming them the same..

Comment: Just a side note here, but your DupCount column is not actually the number of duplicates. It is the number of spaces. Mary has 2 spaces, only 1 of which is a duplicate. Kathy has 5 spaces, of which 4 are duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution for your problem.

```
select studentid, studentname, parkingspace , count(*) dupcount
from tablea inner join tableb on tablea.studentid=tableb.parkingid
group by studentid, studentname, parkingspace having count(*)>1
```

We count the duplicates and by `having count(*)>1` showing only real duplicates.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29c2d/2

Answer (score 2):

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @Table_1 TABLE (StudentID VARCHAR(100),StudentName VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @Table_1 VALUES 
('001','Mary'),('002','Jane'),('003','Peter'),
('004','Smith'),('005','Kathy')

DECLARE @Table_2 TABLE 
(ParkingID VARCHAR(100),ParkingSpace INT)
INSERT INTO @Table_2 VALUES
('001',25),('001',25),('002',18),('003',74),('004',22),('005',31),
('005',31),('005',31),('005',31),('005',31)
```

**Query**

```
SELECT T1.StudentID
      ,T1.StudentName
      ,T2.ParkingSpace
      ,COUNT(T2.ParkingSpace) AS Duplicates

FROM @Table_1 T1 INNER JOIN @Table_2 T2
ON T1.StudentID = T2.ParkingID
GROUP BY  T1.StudentID
         ,T1.StudentName
         ,T2.ParkingSpace
HAVING COUNT(T2.ParkingSpace) > 1
```

**Result Set**

```
╔═══════════╦═════════════╦══════════════╦════════════╗
║ StudentID ║ StudentName ║ ParkingSpace ║ Duplicates ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╬════════════╣
║       001 ║ Mary        ║           25 ║          2 ║
║       005 ║ Kathy       ║           31 ║          5 ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════╩══════════════╩════════════╝
```

Comment: This is not really correct. Jane, Peter and Smith do not have 1 duplicate. They have 1 space and zero duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.studentId, a.studentName, 
b.parkingspace, count(1) as dupcount
from a
join b on a.studentId = b.parkingid
group by a.studentId, a.studentName, b.parkingspace
having dupcount > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  A.studentID,
  A.studentName,
  B.parkingSpace,
  COUNT(B.parkingSpace)
FROM A

JOIN B ON A.StudentID = B.ParkingID

GROUP BY
A.studentID,
  A.studentName,
  B.parkingSpace
```